# textbox change on select

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, combobox, textbox

I have the following code:

```
$sql="SELECT * from customer_billing where sequence = '".$_GET["seq"]."' ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function producttype(data) {
    document.getElementById ("producttype").value = data.value;
    }
    function sagenominalcode(data) {
    document.getElementById ("sagenominalcode").value = data.value;
    }
    </script>
    <form method="post" action="editbillingline.php">
    <table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <td width="50%"><strong>Product Type: </strong>
          <br />
        <select name="producttype-dropdown" id="producttype-dropdown" onchange="producttype(this)">
        <option value="">none</option>
        <?php
        $sql2="SELECT * from customer_billing group by producttype order by producttype ";
        $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $display='';
        while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
        {
            $display.='<option value="'.$result2["producttype"].'"';
            if($result["producttype"]==$result2["producttype"]){$display.=' selected="selected" ';}
            $display.='>'.$result2["producttype"].'</option>';
        }
        echo($display);
        $display='';
        ?>
        </select>
        <input name="producttype" id="producttype" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo $result["producttype"]; ?>" /></td>
```

so it selects from a database which is working fine and then when you change a option in the dropdown box it needs to put the value into the textbox below it. as you can see the combo box is generated from a mysql database.

any ideas on how i can get it to insert the value of the  selected item into the text box?

EDIT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function producttype(data) {
document.getElementById ("producttype").value = data.value;
}
function sagenominalcode(data) {
document.getElementById ("sagenominalcode").value = data.value;
}
</script>
<form method="post" action="editbillingline.php">
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><strong>Product Type: </strong>
      <br />
    <select name="producttype-dropdown" id="producttype-dropdown" onchange="producttype(this)">
    <option value="">none</option>
    <option value="PC Maintenance">PC Maintenance</option><option value="VoIP Telephony" selected="selected" >VoIP Telephony</option>        </select>
    <input name="producttype" id="producttype" type="text" size="30" value="VoIP Telephony" /></td>
```

Comment: We don't need any PHP or MySQL for this question. It's HTML and Javascipt. Could you please edit it?

Comment: He is getting the options from a database

Comment: yhep thats correct :)

Comment: unless you have only a few number of sequences that don't change @charliejsford. in that case hardcoding the options would be much better.

Comment: The PHP and MySQL is irrelevant to the question that is being asked. The point is that you have a dropdown that has some options. Doesn't matter how those options got there. Yes, you use PHP and MySQL. That doesn't make any difference with the question you're asking. Your question only relates to HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: i cannot hard code these at it is always changing from other parts of our system using PHP. im not sure i understand why they are irrelevant?

Comment: Run the script on the browser. Hit CTRL+U to view source, copy the relevant HTML and paste it in your question please.

Comment: I have another code that just selects options and doesnt display if they are already chosen in the database which seems to work ok

Comment: Your PHP is generating the HTML for your `<select>` element. That part is working fine. So now, what we have is an HTML `<select>` element (doesn't matter how it was created), and you want to know how to copy the selected value into a text box. The PHP side is working. So it doesn't matter for your question how the `<select>` element was created.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('producttype-dropdown').addEventListener('change', function(){
        document.getElementById('producttype').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's JavaScript, so it goes inside `<script>` tags. I would place that in your `<head>`, and I would wrap this code in a `window.attachEvent('onload', function() { /* code above goes here */ });`.

Comment: okie dokie thanks - that code seems to have some errors in it?

Comment: aha - i just saw you changed it thanks.
i still seem to be getting errors?